# Using SQL Server table values for variable values in a Visual Studio SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL Server table with only two single-column rows in it, those two values will change from time to time. As an example, the table right now might look like this:

| ThisIsMyColumnName |
| --- |
| Supercalifragilistic |
| Expealidocious |

I also have a Visual Studio SSIS project with variables called `MySQLValueOne` and `MySQLValueTwo` (both of 'String' datatype).

I need Visual Studio to access my SQL Server table, get *both* values, and update my variables with those values from the table. When done, I would have SSIS Package variables that look like the following:

| Name | Data type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MySQLValueOne | String | Supercalifragilistic |
| MySQLValueTwo | String | Expealidocious |

Note: The *order* in which these values are assigned to the variables is unimportant, as long as the two items from my SQL Server table are represented between the two SSIS Package Variables.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I've tired using a ForLoop to read the values from that table into Variables in my SSIS package, but I can't seem to get both of these to read into separate values (not sure I'm trying to use that correctly).

I have also tried using a SQL task, but I'm not familiar enough to identify the two resulting values into separate Package Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your data setup.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (col VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @tbl (col) VALUES
('Supercalifragilistic'),
('Expealidocious');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SELECT TOP(1) col AS col1
    , LEAD(col) OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID DESC) AS col2
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY @@SPID;
```

**Output**

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Supercalifragilistic | Expealidocious |

Now back to SSIS Execute SQL Task

ResultSet = None

**SQL Statement**

We are using question marks as a placeholders for SSIS variables.

```
SELECT TOP(1) ? = col
    , ? = LEAD(col) OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID DESC)
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY @@SPID;
```

**Parameter Mapping tab**

Add both variables with Direction: Output

| Variable Name | Direction | Data Type | Parameter Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User::MySQLValueOne | Output | NVARCHAR | 0 |
| User::MySQLValueTwo | Output | NVARCHAR | 1 |

For the reference: [SELECT statement with output parameters in Execute SQL Task](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBe0eb9HEY0)

Answer (score 0):

In your control flow, add an Execute SQL Task.

I'm sure there's a more clever way to of doing this query, but it works since we'll only ever have 2 rows. Assign it to SQLStatement with the correct table/column substitution

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  MT.col1 AS thing1
, MT2.thing2
FROM mytable AS MT
  CROSS APPLY
  (
  SELECT TOP 1 MT2.col1 AS thing2
  FROM mytable AS MT2
  WHERE MT2.col1 <> MT.col1
  ) MT2;
```

That results in your flattened 2 column thing.

On the General tab of the Execute SQL Task, change the ResultSet from None to SingleRow.

On the Result Set tab, click Add two times.
Replace "NewResultName" with 0 and 1 respectively and in the Variable Name column, select User::MySQLValueOne and User::MySQLValueTwo

This assume an OLE Db Connection Manager. For ODBC, it would 1 and 2 and for ADO.NET based connection managers, they will be the column name (if I remember right).

### Setup

I created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1lOlfkm5) so that you can test running a queries against a working example and seeing how you can transform your real tables and columns against a reference set

```
-- Behold, a table with 1 column and 2 rows
create table mytable
(
  col1 varchar(50)
);

-- Add our two values
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES ('Supercalifragilistic')
, ('Expealidocious');

-- Generate the desired output: 1 row, 2 columns
SELECT TOP 1 
  MT.col1 AS thing1
, MT2.thing2
FROM mytable AS MT
  CROSS APPLY
  (
  SELECT TOP 1 MT2.col1 AS thing2
  FROM mytable AS MT2
  WHERE MT2.col1 <> MT.col1
  ) MT2;

-- An alternate way of generating 1 row, 2 columns
SELECT MIN(MT.col1) AS thing1, MAX(MT.col1) AS thing2
FROM mytable AS MT;
```

Comment: Attempted this (actually tried once, and retried adding this from scratch in case I had potentially copied anything over incorrectly), I'm getting an error:
GET SQL Values: Error: Executing the query [query here]

"Invalid column name 'col1'."

"The multi-part identifier "MT.col1" could not be bound"(...)

I've also tried a couple variations of what you provided in case it was a basic syntax issue. I changed the "col1" portion to "1", "column1" or "[1]", just in case it was anything along those lines, but received mostly the same error.

Comment: Unless you actually have table named `mything` with a column of `col1` it won't work. Yo need to substitute the real table name and presumably the real column name `ThisIsMyColumnName` from your example

Comment: I substituted the table name. I'm somewhat new to this, so I didn't realize that .col1 was a placeholder in your example, thank you for clarifying that for me.

To clarify my understanding and this example:
There is only one column in the table, with two entries. Will this still work if I replace col1 with the actual column name?

Comment: Correct. I updated my answer with a setup + link to dbfiddle so you can run the queries I supplied and then mangle them into your actual environment. And since you're new to all this, providing a table definition and sample values makes it much easier for people on SO to work the problem. In SQL Server Management Studio, SSMS, you can right click on a table and select Script as Create to New Window and there's a table definition ready to go

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that. I was trying to make it as easy as possible, if I need to request assistance on something like this again in the future, I'll be sure to include that as well.